# asp.net, url rewrite module and web.config

Tags: asp.net, url, web-config, module, url-rewriting

i'm using ASP.net with .NET 3.5 on IIS7 (Vista) with the URL Rewrite Module from Microsoft.

This means, that i have a

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>...</rewrite>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

section within the web.config, but i get a warning, that within the system.webServer the element "rewrite" is not allowed.

How can i configure my system to allow (and maybe even have Intellisense) on the rewrite-part of the web.config?

Thank you
Christoph

Comment: I can confirm that this problem still occurs in VS2010 and IIS7.5.

Comment: this causes a build on my mvc project to fail. pretty bad.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was able to get this working in Visual Studio 2010.

Start with Ruslan's post [here](http://ruslany.net/2010/04/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-2-0/) and download the 2.0 IntelliSense file.  Then, just follow the directions he posted previously [here](http://ruslany.net/2009/08/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-1-1/).  All I ended up doing was running the following command as Ruslan instructs:

`C:\download_directory\rewrite2_intellisense>cscript UpdateSchemaCache.js`

As Christoph points out in his comment, make sure you replace `VS90COMNTOOLS` with `VS100COMNTOOLS` in UpdateSchemaCache.js before running the above command if you are using Visual Studio 2010.

I did not need to restart Visual Studio.  I added the `<rewrite>` section only to the applicable Web.config transformation files, as having it in the main Web.config breaks local debugging.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the link. Works good in vs2010 but be aware if you use vs2010 you need to change in the UpdateSchemaCache.js the "VS90COMNTOOLS" to "VS100COMNTOOLS" (hint for other users :-) )

Comment: Hi Jonathan. About that web.config transform - what does yours look like? The only way I can see to do it is to add a second system.webServer section containing the <rewrite> and <rules>. I'd rather not add a second <system.webServer> section. Do you have a more elegant way?

Comment: @Jon FreeLand - I get this error(even though I am running it the cmd prompt as an admin) Failed to open file Xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig.xsd. Make sure that the script is run in the elevated command prompt.

Comment: So do I. Is there a problem with the Express Version of VS 2010?

Comment: Sorry guys, I do not know if this will work with Express. I am using Ultimate.

Comment: That guys article is frustrating to follow. It gives you the rewrite code, but doesn't tell you where exactly to place it in the web.config.

Comment: Ruslan's website is gone. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to have the URL Rewrite Module "installed" within the web.config file on your system.

You either need to install the module on your application via the IIS 7.0 interface or have your hosting firm do it for you.

Comment: nope, i installed the Rewrite Module several times on several Mashines (Vista and Win7) via the Web Platform Installer 2.0 and the native Installer from IIS.net

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I believe you need to define the module in your web.config like this:</strike>

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Update: Intellisense can be setup here:

http://ruslany.net/2009/08/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-1-1/

Update: Verify that the sectionGroup is identified in %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config:

```
<sectionGroup name="rewrite">
    <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="globalRules" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
    <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Comment: Hi,

i actually have this (for rewrite 2,.0):
<sectionGroup name="rewrite">
    <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="globalRules" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
    <section name="outboundRules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="providers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
</sectionGroup>

but the problem still exists...