# The element > system.webServer' has invalid child > element 'rewrite'

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

> Warning   1   The element
>   'system.webServer' has invalid child
>   element 'rewrite'. List of possible
>   elements expected: 'asp, caching, cgi,
>   defaultDocument, directoryBrowse,
>   globalModules, handlers,
>   httpCompression, httpErrors,
>   httpLogging, httpProtocol,
>   httpRedirect, httpTracing,
>   isapiFilters, modules, odbcLogging,
>   security, serverRuntime,
>   serverSideInclude, staticContent,
>   tracing, urlCompression, validation,
>   management'.  D:\PROJEKTI\FoodOrder\FoodOrder\Web.config  185 4   FoodOrder

code:

```
system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="ScriptModule" />
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
            <remove name="ScriptResource" />
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites">
                    <!--<add key="/Default.aspx" value="/Default.aspx" />-->
                </rewriteMap>
            </rewriteMaps>
            <rules>
```

page works but i always get warning of this and when i publish page i get publish error becouse of this...

Answer (score 26):

Possible duplicate of [asp.net, url rewrite module and web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363231/asp-net-url-rewrite-module-and-web-config)

This happens when Visual Studio IntelliSense doesn't find information about rewrite module on schema file. Hence we need to add schema for rewrite section in a file specifically: DotNetConfig.xsd

Ruslan provides unofficial schema for rewrite. For Visual Studio 2010, please download xml schema from his page: http://ruslany.net/2010/04/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-2-0/

For earlier versions download from here:
http://ruslany.net/2009/08/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-1-1/#comment-1402

For both versions, instructions are [here](http://ruslany.net/2009/08/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-1-1/#comment-1402).

For VS2010 remember to replace `%VS90COMNTOOLS%` with `%VS100COMNTOOLS%`

For VS2012 and later, follow [fftsys's article](https://atiqcs.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/visual-studio-intellisense-not-working-with-rewrite-module/).

If you do not want to use ruslany's script you can still use rewrite module. In that case, you still can modify web.config to add rewrite section out of visual studio.

Original rewrite module for IIS comes from Microsoft: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite and supported by them. ruslany's script just enables support in Visual Studio so that VS recognizes it.

Comment: Here is some details on VS2012 as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120726/url-rewrite-with-visual-studio-2012

Comment: By reading the Disclaimer that has been provided there it`s very difficult to implement this. As in any case this could cause a failure then ?

Comment: @AbidAli: please check last two paras of the answer.

Comment: That webpage looks like it might be dead. Is there anywhere else we can get it?

Comment: We can notify him that his site is down - https://forums.iis.net/members/ruslany.aspx

or I will upload a copy myself if I find a copy in my computer. That I will do after I return from work.