# DotNetConfig.xsd missing webserver element?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, xsd, url-rewriting

I have Vs 2010 and I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://ruslany.net/2010/04/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-2-0/)  to correct a warning I am getting.

However once I changed it to `"%VS100COMNTOOLS%"` per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309059/the-element-system-webserver-has-invalid-child-element-rewrite)  I get
this error

> The definition for the `<system.webServer>` element is not found in the
>   file C:\Pr ogram Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig.xsd.

So I went to this foldre and I see

```
DotNetConfig.xsd
DotNetConfig20.xsd
DotNetConfig30.xsd
DotNetConfig35.xsd
```

I am guessing each one is for the .net version(not sure where 4.0 is). I looked into DotNetConfig.xsd and found I don't have that element. I then looked into all the other ones and they do. So should the first not have this or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should. From a standard install, the following can be found at line 22804 in DotNetConfig.xsd:

```
<xs:element name="system.webServer" vs:help="configuration/system.webServer">
```

Comment: Hmm my home computer has it but my work computer does not. Also another co-workers computer does not. The only difference I can think off is that those computers are 64bit windows and mine is 32bit. Why would I be missing it and how can I restore the file so it would have it in there?

Comment: @chobo2, the one I used as a reference in my answer comes from a x64 install. As to restoring the file, I would simply copy a good copy over and then take it from there.