# url rewrite with visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to use the url rewrite module with an MVC application on VS 2012.
I've installed the module using web platform 4.0, followed Ruslan's blog [post](http://ruslany.net/2009/08/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-1-1/), updated his js script according to the comments (specifically the last one by Brant Burnett on Oct 19th, and the script executed successfully. I checked the DotNetConfig.xsd and everything looks fine.

If I open IIS management console I see the Url Rewrite module and everything looks ok.

I create an simple MVC solution (with the default home/account controller), and when I add the simplest ToLowerCase rule (also copied from Ruslan's blog), I get the blue squiggly line under the  tag and an http 500.19 if I try to execute. rebooting, etc. does not help. also important to mention I use IIS express 7.5.

the same procedure worked for me fine on a machine running VS 2010, url rewriting worked without a problem.

anyone knows what could go wrong? what info is needed for further analysis? why isn't intellisense working and the rewrite module recognized?

Comment: Same here. From what I can tell, VS2012 doesn't even use the DotNetConfig.xsd file

Answer (score 7):

The problem lies in version of .NET Framework, each version has its own config intellisense file. Additional hassle is that the file for 4.5 isn't in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas\`, as `DotNetConfig45.xsd`, but in additional folder `1033`.

Here I updated RuslanY's setup script for VS 2012 and .NET 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5:
http://pastebin.com/8GGGHTBL

Comment: As in it is here?  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas\1033\DotNetConfig.xsd  ???

Comment: Where/How do I run that script? I'm guessing the link in the question answers that but the link is not working.

Comment: @ColinMackay Use this instruction http://ruslany.net/2009/08/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-1-1/ with this script http://pastebin.com/8GGGHTBL