# Getting the current URL that is shown in the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, request

Currently I'm trying to get the current URL that is shown in the browser.

If I use

```
Request.Path
```

I get https://this.website.com:443/Default.aspx which is technically correct.

However the URL displayed in the browser itself is https://this.website.com/.

Using any of the Request options still will show Default.aspx.

I need to ultimately detect wether or not the url in the browser is https://this.website.com or http://this.website.com/Default.aspx and then redirect to Default.aspx if it's not there.

Btw complicating things more is the https redirect in my web.config.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get the URL of the current page in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. What I'm trying to figure out is how to distinguish the difference between http://www.site.com/ and http://www.site.com/Default.aspx. Which apparently asp.net determines to be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it from the request in the [httpcontext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

**Updated:**

If you want to tell wether the current url is / or /default.aspx. You can use the [**RawUrl**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx) property of the request. This field will contain the whole url.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl
```

Comment: Nope it brings up https://this.website.com/default.aspx when the url in the browser window is https://this.website.com/

Comment: You'll have to use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`

Comment: @DanielB Nope. that only gives me the HOST. I need to find out whether or not the url is this.site.com/ or this.site.com/Default.aspx.

Comment: @Prescient then use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` and make a check?

Comment: nope. what is returned is /Default.aspx and the browser shows http://www.site.com/

Comment: Then maybe check this: [How to tell if a user is visiting “/Default.aspx” or just “/”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629232/how-to-tell-if-a-user-is-visiting-default-aspx-or-just)

Comment: Peter is correct. Request.RawUrl is the way to go. I will be checking Request.RawUrl.Lenth.ToString() for a value less than 2 and redirect if it's found.  Thanks.