# Published web site does't recogonize the rewrite element in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

All, I was stuck with a problem when I deploy a web site. I found there is an element named  `rewrite` in the web.config.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <!-- below rule will abort api request when the request to pattern "apis/v.*" is of "http" method-->
            <rule name="AbortApiHTTPRequest">
                <!-- Note:
                        the below pattern is assumed that all apis conain prefix "apis/v", e.g. apis/v3/aaauth
                        if there are some exceptions for the assumption, below pattern needs to be updated.
                -->
                <match url="^apis/v.*$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="AbortRequest" />
            </rule>

            <!-- below rule will redirect all non-https requests except for above requests to https request.-->
            <rule name="RedirectToHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^.*$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:0}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

When I remove the element everthing is ok, the website works well. Otherwise I got a error says.

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.

After I did some research, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280803/element-system-webserver-has-invalid-child-element-rewrite-should-i-fix-thi) talking about it. I am not sure if it is the cause of the problem. seems it is just a xml syntax validation of `Visual studio`. Does it really matter with the deployment of web site in IIS 7?

Anyway, I also followed the instructions of the post , But I failed to get it works .even I run the `cmd` as the administrator. the error says below.

> Failed to open file Xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig.xsd. Make sure that the
>   script is run in the elevated command prompt.

I wandered if I have the enough previlige to run `cscript` command ? thanks.

**More**

If I run the project in the Visual Studio with the `Asp.net development server`, It can work without any error. But If I published the project to the IIS in my computer.  It doen't work.

Comment: If you visit the website locally (i.e. on the same machine as the IIS service) do you get extended error information?

Comment: Yes, I published it in the IIS of my computer, and acess it in my computer, The full error information could be showed in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rewrite directive is used by [URLRewrite module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

If the module is not installed, you will get an error similar to the above. You can either install the module if you need URLRewriting - or - comment out the entire `<rewrite>` section.

Comment: +1 How can I find out if the module is installed or not ? thanks.

Comment: In IIS manager, locate and click the website in the left hand pane; in the middle pane, you should see "URL Rewrite" under "HTTP Features" section. It does not ship with IIS or installed by default.

Comment: Other method is to open "Modules" under "Server Components" and see if `RewriteModule: %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll` exists in that list.

Comment: Yeah, It is not installed yet. But A question comes out of my mind, Isn't the Url rewriting implemented in the HttpModule or HttpHandler? thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I have only used this module (on IIS7 and IIRF on IIS6) for URL rewriting.