# HTTP Error 500.52 - Internal Server Error & <rewrite> tag in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, web-config

Actually I am getting error "**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**" on http://studiowavesapp.in/. I searched for solution of same. Need to add some setting  in web.config.But facing issue in adding that also.

[image: Error in Web.config]

If any one can help me, it would be very nice.

Rewrite Code, I am using .framework 4.0

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        rules go here
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Try activating [**failed request tracing**](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) in IIS and see if there are any clues there.  You might have an invalid rewrite rule, or some sort of infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for response mate, but I am hosting my website on Purchased Windows Hosting account, But don't have IIS Option directly.So what else can be done?

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `<rewrite>` rules you have setup in web.config?  Is this a 3rd-party tool you are using for your website or something you've built?

Comment: I have built web application on my own using ASP.NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2008. Now I am hosting it on Third party server, purchased from  Hostingraja.in

Comment: Please let me know, if I can give some more information.

Comment: Can you show the actual rules you are using?

Comment: I am not able to write any rules, when I put <rewrite> tag, it says invalid child element <rewrite> in <system.webServer>.

Comment: It sounds like the hosting company has rewrite module turned off by default, or it isn't configured properly.  I think it would be best to take this up with their support staff.

Comment: OK mate will do that, thank you so much for your time.Will talk with them, if still it results to error then will trouble you. :)

Comment: If you search for your error message, there are some similar posts on SO about setting up the correct schema for VS to see the intellisense.  For example, take a look at these: [**1**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280803/element-system-webserver-has-invalid-child-element-rewrite-should-i-fix-thi) [**2**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309059/the-element-system-webserver-has-invalid-child-element-rewrite)